# Xamarin Android Animation Change Place

Tags: android, xamarin

I have a image view in my relative layout.
I am trying to move this image view from left to right

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    imgEl.Left += 10;
    imgEl.SetZ(100);
    //Thread.Sleep(100);
 }
```

First: I can't see its movement.

Second: sometimes it gets under another control.

Comment: probably because you are messing with your Z-index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all. You are not manipulating the X coordinate. Second of all, if you uncomment `Thread.Sleep(100)` and you are on the UI Thread, you will block it and no animation will happen.

Why don't you use `ObjectAnimator` instead to do your animation?

Moving your image 100 pixels to the right would be as easy as:

```
var animation = ObjectAnimator.OfFloat(imageView, "translationX", 100f);
animation.SetDuration(250);
animation.Start();
```

Where `imageView` is the reference to your image. `translationX` is the property that is being animated. `100f` is the value to animate.

No need for making your own loops or creating threads or anything.

Comment: Thanks @Cheesebaron. That is what I am looking for. But the animation works fonly one time. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: What do you mean it only works one time? Are you changing the value that you want to animate to?

Comment: Animation is working, image view is moving to right. I am not changing the code. But when I call the code second time, animation doesn't work. I don't know why.

Comment: Yes, because you keep setting the translationX to the same value.

Comment: I tried different values, but it works just one time. If I find a solution, I will write it here.